# QBO: Setting OAuth tokens expiration

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

After the last changes at Quickbooks site, I can't find a place where I can get OAuth tokens and set their expiration time. I need to automate the reconnect process but just read about tokens expiration in 180 days. I would need to get a set of token that expire quite earlier so that I can test my code without waiting so may days for it to be executed. Is that possible?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the playground to test with - https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA/?ck=consumer_key&cs=consumer_secret

Comment: How do you get the accessToken and accessTokenSecret when using this?